# Blender 2.8 - Bone "Custom Object" is not displaying when it's an empty object

Tags: armature, 3d-view, bones

I build a model in Blender 2.79 with an armature and IK rigging.  The model has specific "touch bones" that you manipulate to pose it, and these each have a "Custom Object" set so you can manipulate them.  E.g., the touch bone for the head appears as a circle around the head (screenshot below.) A few of the touch bones use empty "Empties" as their Custom Objects, such as an axis or a sphere.

This all looks and works fine when I open the model in Blender 2.79.  I can see and manipulate all of the touch bones.  However, when I open it in Blender 2.8, none of the touch bones using empty objects appear in the view.  Is this a change in the code, a bug or oversight, or is there some setting I can change to rectify this?

For example, in the pictures below you can see in 1.79 (top picture) that there is an axis in the center of the figure, and spheres projecting from the elbows and ankles, but in 1.8 these things are not visible in the same model.

[image: Blender 2.79, Center Axis and Sphere Bones Visible]

[image: Blender 2.8, Center Axis and Sphere Bones Not Visible]

Answer (score 1):

In order for custom shapes to display, you must check the `shapes` option under "Viewport Display" in the "Armature" properties.

[image]